# ReactJS ES6 syntax for handling events

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I am fairly new to ReactJS, Redux and ES6, and I am trying to implement an event-handler where my chat body would hide or unhide as i click the header (kind of like what Facebook chat widget does). My problem is I cannot get the syntax correctly from a copied source. Here is my code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import chat from './styles.css';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class ChatWidget extends Component {

  handleClick(event) {
    console.log("test")
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={chat.box}>

        <div className={chat.container}>

          <div onClick={onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}} 
               className={chat.header}>
            <span className={chat.name}>Idol</span>
          </div>

          <div className={chat.body}>
            This is the Body of the chat
          </div>

          <div className={chat.chat}>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Ask anything..." />
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    user: state.activeUser
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ChatWidget);
```

Error:

```
> 16 |           <div onClick={onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}}
     |                                      ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

`onClick={onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}}`

Write this:

`onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}`

Comment: that was a sloppy one. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way of doing bindings is in the constructor because they will be created only once, not on every render().

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.myFn = this.myFn.bind(this);
  }

  myFn() {
    // code goes here
  }

  render() {
    // code goes here also

    return <button onClick={this.myFn}>Look ma no .bind() here</button>;
  }
}
```